# aws elastic beanstalk nginx reverse proxy settings

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, reverse-proxy, elastic-beanstalk

I think I might have posted in the wrong place (stackoverflow) but instead of reposting here which would make it duplicates, I will paste the link in stackoverflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55069430/aws-elastic-beanstalk-nginx-reverse-proxy-settings

Sorry for any inconveniences.